# Python-I am getting an unexpected character after line continuation character error

Tags: python

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? I am trying to make an equation so when the user inputs a number of feet, the program can respond by translating it into miles. Here is what my code looks like. Thanks! :)

```
number_of_feet = 10,560
miles= (number_of_feet \ 5,280)
print(miles)
```

Comment: Division is `/`, not `\\`. Please read the python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `,` in an integer.  `5,280` should be `5280` and `10,560` should be `10560`

Python division uses `/`, not `\`.

```
number_of_feet = 10560
miles= (number_of_feet / 5280)
print(miles)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm at the most basic level of programming, I'm in my first course in college right now and I'm just getting the basics of this. Thanks again! :)